# How to install cPickle on Python 3.4?

Tags: software-installation, python3

I tried `sudo apt-get install cPickle` and `python3.4-cPickle` but it doesn't work.

Comment: I would assume you install a python module with `pip`?

Comment: can you give me the command please

Comment: AFAIK, in python 3, you use `pickle` only. Internally it will use `cpickle` if available.
See https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#library-changes

Answer (score 78, accepted):

There is no `cPickle` in python 3:

> A common pattern in Python 2.x is to have one version of a module implemented in pure Python, with an optional accelerated version implemented as a C extension; for example, pickle and cPickle. This places the burden of importing the accelerated version and falling back on the pure Python version on each user of these modules. In Python 3.0, the accelerated versions are considered implementation details of the pure Python versions. Users should always import the standard version, which attempts to import the accelerated version and falls back to the pure Python version. The pickle / cPickle pair received this treatment.

-[Source](https://docs.python.org/3.1/whatsnew/3.0.html#library-changes).

Comment: "the accelerated versions are considered implementation details of the pure Python versions": what does this exactly mean?

Comment: @Basj: It means you should `import pickle`, not `import cPickle`.

Comment: @basj, "Implementation detail" means something that should be hidden from us users.  We just want the pickle functionality and should not care if its implemented in python or c.  So, it means don't make us understand...python just do the best thing.

Answer (score 6):

From the [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#performance)  module documentation:

> The `pickle` module has an transparent optimizer (`_pickle`) written in C. It is used whenever available. Otherwise the pure Python implementation is used.

In `python3` use:

```
import _pickle as cPickle
```

Comment: Have I misunderstood this? `python3.8 -m pip install pickle`. Output:
`ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pickle (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for pickle`. How should I install it then?

Comment: @questionto42standswithUkraine have you tried just importing pickle? It is a built-in so you shouldn't need to install it at all.

Comment: Built-in sounds good, might be that I have not checked it.